# Get multiple values from XML field stored as Varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server

I have this value in a varchar(max) column in SQL Server:

```
<VersionSeries><SeriesTypeIdList><int>3</int><int>4</int><int>2</int><int>29</int><int>31</int><int>32</int><int>39</int></SeriesTypeIdList></VersionSeries
```

I want to get the int values out into a table.

This is the code I have but it is only returning the first record it finds.

```
Declare @Version varchar(100)
Select @Version = '2016A Demo'

DECLARE @DataTable TABLE
(
    Xml XML NOT NULL,
    Code NVARCHAR(50) NULL

)
INSERT 
INTO @DataTable(Xml)
SELECT
    CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), Series))
FROM Version
where VersionName = @Version

Create table #SeriesCodes
  (Code integer)

  Insert Into #SeriesCodes
    (Code)
SELECT
     T.c.value('int[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as Code
FROM  @DataTable d
    OUTER APPLY d.Xml.nodes('/VersionSeries/SeriesTypeIdList') T(c);


    Select * from #SeriesCodes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a single statement to get what you want:

```
DECLARE @x2 XML = N'<VersionSeries><SeriesTypeIdList><int>3</int><int>4</int><int>2</int><int>29</int><int>31</int><int>32</int><int>39</int></SeriesTypeIdList></VersionSeries>';

SELECT t.c.query(N'.').value(N'(/*)[1]', N'int') AS [int_value]
FROM   @X2.nodes(N'/VersionSeries/SeriesTypeIdList/*') AS [t]([c]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Declare @Version varchar(100)
Select @Version = '2016A Demo'

DECLARE @DataTable TABLE
(
    Xml XML NOT NULL,
    Code NVARCHAR(50) NULL

)
INSERT 
INTO @DataTable(Xml)
values (N'<VersionSeries><SeriesTypeIdList><int>3</int><int>4</int><int>2</int><int>29</int><int>31</int><int>32</int><int>39</int></SeriesTypeIdList></VersionSeries>')

SELECT
     T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)') as Code
FROM  @DataTable d
    OUTER APPLY d.Xml.nodes('/VersionSeries/SeriesTypeIdList/int') T(c);
```